# function json_extract_path_text(super, "unknown") does not exist - Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

Alright. I have a table that has SUPER type fields. These fields hold values like below:

```
id  mycol
---------------------------------
1   [{"Title":"first"},{"Title":"Second"},{"Title":"Third"},{"Title":"fourth"}]
2   [{"Title":"some"},{"Title":"thing"}]
3   [{"Title":"else"}]
```

I want to extract the JSON values and concatenate them with commas in each row.

My current query:

```
    with cte as (
    SELECT id, mycol
    FROM mytable t, t.mycol AS item AT index
)
select id, item."Title" from cte
```

This generates output as:

```
    id  mycol
    -------------
    1   first
    1   second
    1   third
    1   fourth
    2   some

......and so on
```

I want my results to be:

```
id  mycol
-------------
1   first,second,third,fourth
2   some,thing
3   else
```

So to merge rows with same ID, I used LISSTAG:

```
SELECT id, LISTAGG(item."Title",' ') AS mycol
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id
```

this throws error that `LISTAGG(Super) is not available`. So any function on SUPER field is throwing unavailable error.

I don't want to leave them as SUPER fields because further conversions/implementations like LISTAGG/CONCAT is becoming difficult. So I want to see convert the field to varchar after extraction from JSON style.  any help?

Comment: Share what you expect the output to be. Do you want 4 rows?

Comment: i want a single row and comma separated list. `with cte as (
    SELECT id,(item::varchar)
    FROM mytable t, t.mycolAS item AT index
)select id, item."Title" from cte` this query generates 4 rows but when I try to aggregate them using LISTAGG i get the error. so i want to convert my super field to varchar to do any operations

Comment: Show what you want it to look like in your post. Don't describe it.

Comment: Modified my question and indicated exactly what i need

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a problem with inferring the argument type. Try [casting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CAST_function.html) it explicitly to `VARCHAR`

```
SELECT json_extract_path_text(mycol::VARCHAR,'Title'::VARCHAR) AS item1 FROM mytable
```

Comment: function json_extract_path_text(super, character varying) does not exist. this is trying to cast only the "Title" not the field

Comment: Oh, then try casting the `mycol` to `TEXT` or `VARCHAR`. I have no way to test it myself at the moment. But I have seen errors saying `function ... does not exist` when the types were not correct, so that rings the bell.

Answer (score 0):

By default Redshift is case insensitive for identifiers.  "SELECT FOO from table;" and "SELECT foo from table;" are exactly the same.

This presents a problem when it comes to SUPER data types as the identifiers in the SUPER are case sensitive.  So if you use other than lower case identifiers in your SUPER columns you need to tell Redshift to be case sensitive by running

```
SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier TO true;
```

Since your SUPER has the identifier "Title" which uses upper case I'm suspecting that this is your issue.  Just be careful as the above two select examples won't produce the same result after you set case sensitivity.

Comment: This is enabled for me at user level

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
create temp table mytable (id int, mycol super);
insert into mytable
values

(1,   '[{"Title":"first"},{"Title":"Second"},{"Title":"Third"},{"Title":"fourth"}]'),
(2 ,  '[{"Title":"some"},{"Title":"thing"}]'),
(3  , '[{"Title":"else"}]');

SET enable_case_sensitive_super_attribute to TRUE;
with cte as (
    select
        x.id,
        json_parse(x.mycol::varchar) as json_str
    from mytable x
    ), 
    final AS (
    select x.id, 
           unnested.Title AS title
    from cte x, x.json_str as unnested 
    order by id
    )

select id, 
       listagg(title::varchar, ', ')
from final
group by 1
order by id;
RESET enable_case_sensitive_super_attribute;

+--+----------------------------+
|id|listagg                     |
+--+----------------------------+
|1 |first, Second, Third, fourth|
|2 |some, thing                 |
|3 |else                        |
+--+----------------------------+
```